Puzzling Advent Calendar - 2024
Previous years: 2021, 2022, 2023

There will be a Christmas-themed puzzle every day between the 1st and 24th of December, where the accepted answer will be rewarded with a bounty.
To make this work, we need a few users who are willing to prepare nice puzzles for this event. Note that the awarding of bounties is handled separately, so you can join without having to give reputation away (although you can optionally choose to award a bounty yourself). To post a puzzle for this event, you should meet the following criteria:

You have posted at least one question on PSE with a vote score of at least 5.
The puzzle is Christmas-themed (seasonal).
The title of the puzzle should be PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day X): {puzzle title}.
A header with a link to this post and the previous/next entries of the calendar (if and when available): <sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7612). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth {X} reputation.<br><br>[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](link) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](link)</sub><hr>
If possible, please post a hint every ~24 hours as long as your puzzle remains unsolved.

Please do not announce your participation in an answer or comment to this post. We will plan the allocations of puzzles in a spreadsheet and coordinate / discuss puzzles in this dedicated chat room.

1214220804
0901201713
1519 1016
0621072303
1805110224
List of all questions posted as part of the PSE Advent Calendar 2024:

PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 1): A Snowy Christmas
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 2): Roleplaying Reindeer
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 3): A cacophonic crossword
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 4): "Where should Declan go?" - a GCHQ word association puzzle (Christmas edition)
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 5): 835
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 6): Colorful Gifts
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 7): Santa’s in a pickle!
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 8): Look, Santa’s Baffled
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 9): Special Wrapping Paper
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 10): Locked Christmas Present
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 11): A Sparkling Sudoku
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 12): 12 Days of Gaming
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 13): ‘Tis the Season for... Diamonds?
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 14): Chess with gravity #3
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 15): 2122
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 16): Holly Jolly Cryptic Word Tapestry
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 17): The Sun Will Come Out Tomorrow
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 18): A sweet & short expected chemistry Christmas puzzle
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 19): A Christmas puzzle in (1)225 characters
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 20): Holly
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 21): Wrap-Up
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 22): Away in a Manger
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 23): 2089
PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 24): 'Twas the Meta before Christmas

